# What is the proper way to update database on production after model has changed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

My MVC5 project has `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;`

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
}
```

Whenever I have to change my model in code I have to run `add-migration "some_name"` and `update-database` to have my database on my dev machine updated.

But, when I published my project to deploy on my production I have an error because the database on my production has not been updated.

To have my database on my production updated I have to add this line of code to my Global.asax.cs

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DAL.AppContext, Configuration>());
```

My question is: is this a correct way of doing it? Will there be any risk of losing data?

And most importantly, what does this line of code do exactly? Does anyone has a full picture/idea of what it does?

Thanks

Comment: This is Entity Framework, not MVC.

Comment: Generate SQL scripts and execute them. Anything that touches production must be artifactable, auditable, and "rollback-able".

Comment: Is the way i am doing is wrong? I mean is it wrong to add that line of code to my `global.asax.cs`? What does that line of code do exactly, does anyone knows?

Comment: Chris Pratt outlines the basic methods [here](https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/). You could also look at DbMigrator in code or migrate.exe as a build/deploy step. Yes, there is always a risk of losing data so always have a backup before updating a production database.

Comment: What does that line of code do exactly do you know? Can you please explain what it does?

Comment: SetInitializer() ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646111/entity-framework-migrations-enable-automigrations-along-with-added-migration

Comment: @ Steve that is not the same because my `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` is set to `false`

Comment: That makes no difference. Guess I'm not sure what you are asking. You use `SetInitializer` with `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` to tell EF to apply your pending migrations. You can place this in your global.asax, but I prefer to put it in the static constructor of my context.

Comment: @ code4life I ran `update-database -verbose` and I got the sql script. Do I just execute this script on my prod server db?